# bash: sudo: command not found on debian jessie

Tags: linux, debian, sudo

I recently installed Debian 8 on my laptop, and when I tried to use "sudo" it responded with

```
bash: sudo: command not found`
```

Then I ran the following command

```
/usr/bin/sudo
```

I got the following error

```
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory
```

After that when I tried to install it with `apt-get` I got this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  sudo
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/850 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,694 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Debian GNU/Linux 8.0.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 CD Binary-1 20150425-12:54'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter
```

Comment: I found it!
source.list in /etc/apt/source.list was empty!
for someone that has a same problem: go to the bellow link and find your country and copy links to source.list or search debian source list generator
https://www.debian.org/mirror/list-full

Comment: please add your solution as a proper "Answer" and mark it as "accepted", so the problem doesn't show up on searches for questions needing answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the issue! The file `source.list` in `/etc/apt/source.list` was empty! If you have the same problem, go to the link below and find your country, then copy the links to source.list or search Debian source list generator
[debian.org/mirror/list-full](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list-full)

Answer (score -3):

Try "sudo su" to get root access instead of trying only "sudo". Hope it helps